# need help Action script 3 keyboard input

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, action

I want to make a game, and I just found a tutorial on making a rhythm game on this website http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-make-a-rhythm-game-in-as3-part-7/, and i need help for change this arrow input to a keyboard input, Lik "W" "A" "S" etc, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [this page of the tutorial](http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-make-a-rhythm-game-in-as3-part-4/) there is a code snippet of `function makeLvl(e:Event):void`. In this function the arrows are assigned a keycode via `currentArrow.arrowCode = 37;`.

AS3 uses a unique number to identify each key on the users keyboard. These are called keycodes. Here's a [list of keycodes](http://www.makeflashgames.com/resources/keycodes.php).

Note that the keycode `37` maps to the `left arrow`-key. You will want to change this value to the keycode of the `A`-key, which is `65`.

Instead of writing these numbers in your code, you can keep your code readable by using the constants provided by the [Keyboard class](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html). It has one for every key.

To map this particular arrow to the the `A`-key, you would write this instead: 
`currentArrow.arrowCode = Keyboard.A;`

For the remaining 3 arrows, look up what arrow-key the assigned keycode maps to, and assign them the appropriate character-key in the same manner.

Comment: 1 question, how can i copy scene without any error with the script ?, i trying to copy game script from scene 1 to scene 2,